# puppet add user to local windows group

Tags: windows, puppet

For a couple of weeks I'm struggling with puppet. I do have it pretty much working but i keep getting issues to add a user to the built-in group "Administrators".

I do can add an user to that group, but removing is not possible. This is an local user, without a domain-controler

Here is my manifest:

```
#Adding user to administrators-group;
class developers {
    user {'user_erik':
        name            => 'Erik.dev',
        ensure          => present,
        comment         => 'Developer',
        groups          => ['Administrators],
        membership      => inclusive,
        password        => 'blaat123',
    }
}
#removing (not working);
class developers {
    user {'user_erik':
        name            => 'Erik.dev',
        ensure          => present,
        comment         => 'Developer',
        groups          => [],
        membership      => inclusive,
        password        => 'blaat123',
    }
}

# another way to set this up;
class developers {
  user {'user_erik':
        name            => 'Eric.dev',
        ensure          => present,
        comment         => 'Developer',
        groups          => [],
        membership      => inclusive,
        password        => 'blaat123',
    }
  group{'admin':
        name            => 'Administrators',
        ensure          => present,
        members         => ['Erik.dev'],
    }
}
```

getting error:
Error: 
OLE error code:8007055B in Active Directory 
" Cannot perform this operation on built-in accounts "

In UNIX I have no problems, but windows is almost killing me and I cannot find my answer on the internet.

Hope someone has it working.

thanks
Dave

Comment: What version of Puppet are you on? I think there was known issues with groups prior to Puppet 3.4 / PE 3.2

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume this is a copy pasta error:

```
user {'user_erik':
    name            => 'Erik.dev',
    ensure          => present,
    comment         => 'Developer',
    groups          => ['Administrators],
    membership      => inclusive,
    password        => 'blaat123',
}
```

note groups is missing an apostrophe. `groups => ['Administrators]` should be `groups => ['Administrators']`

Let's take a look at the remove:

```
user {'user_erik':
    name            => 'Erik.dev',
    ensure          => present,
    comment         => 'Developer',
    groups          => [],
    membership      => inclusive,
    password        => 'blaat123',
}
```

I think you are running into a derivative of  [PUP-3653](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-3653), where you are trying to remove a user from all groups. I would instead put the user in at least one group (perhaps `'Users'`?).

#### Group Membership

With groups, you must specify the complete list of members. [Group](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#group-attribute-auth_membership) `auth_membership => minimum` is ignored in less than Puppet 4.0.0. See [PUP-2628](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-2628) and [PUP-3719](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-3719) for details.

The error

> Error: OLE error code:8007055B in Active Directory " Cannot perform
>   this operation on built-in accounts "

is most likely related to:

```
group{'admin':
    name            => 'Administrators',
    ensure          => present,
    members         => ['Erik.dev'],
}
```

Right now you would need to specify the complete list and you can't remove built-in accounts from the Administrators group. Because this isn't the complete list, Puppet is attempting to remove LocalSystem from the list and running into issues, generating the error you see above.

In Puppet 4.x you can specify it like the above or you can specify it like this:

```
group{'admin':
    name            => 'Administrators',
    ensure          => present,
    members         => ['Erik.dev'],
    auth_membership => false,
}
```